# Why would I use Enumerable.ElementAt() versus the [] operator?

Tags: c#

This seems like a silly question, but I haven't found the answer, so here it is.  :)

In both cases, you will get an "out-of-range" exception if you fail to check the bounds of your collection.  Is this just coding style preference?

And in case someone needs an example:

```
List<byte> myList = new List<byte>(){0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
byte testByte = myList.ElementAt(2);
```

versus

```
byte testByte = myList[2];
```

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338680/whats-the-point-of-enumerable-elementattsource

Comment: Worth to mention to be careful with `string`. It's better to use an indexer for a string instead of `ElementAt`. (i.e. `myString[999]` is better than `myString.ElementAt(999)`). This is related with performance. `String` doesn't implement `IList', thus it won't be randomly-accessed by `ElementAt`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Because `Enumerable` is more generic, and a collection represented by enumerable may not have an indexer.

But, if it does - don't use `ElementAt()` it's probably not going to be as efficient.

Comment: `ElementAt()` is just fine for `IList`s, if you look at the code for it, it casts to an IList and if it succeeds it uses `[]`. This is generally true of all LINQ extension methods.

Comment: I always figured there'd be collection-specific implementations of the extension methods, but without checking I wasn't going to go out on a limb...

Answer (score 32):

`ElementAt()` provides a unified interface for all enumerations in C#. I tend to use it quite often as I like the common API.

If the underlying type supports random access (ie, it supports the `[]` operator), then ElementAt will make use of that. So the only overhead is an extra method call (which is almost never relevant).

If the underlying type does not support random access, then `ElementAt()` simulates it by iterating the enumeration until it arrives at the element you care about. This can be very expensive and even have side effects sometimes.

There is also `ElementAtOrDefault()` which is often very handy.

Comment: +1 good argument. A slight nitpicking. Its more accurate to say `If the underlying type supports random access (ie, it implements `IList<T>`)` **than** `If the underlying type supports random access (ie, it supports the [] operator)`. Just saying.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `ElementAt()` sometimes needs to partially iterate the collection and the potential downsides of that.

Answer (score 20):

AVOID using ElementAt() in certain scenarios!!!

If you know you're going to look up each element, and you have (or could have) over 500, then just call ToArray(), store it in a reusable array variable, and index it off that way.

For example;  my code was reading data from of an Excel file.
I was using ElementAt() to find the SharedStringItem my Cell was referencing.
With 500 or less lines, you probably won't notice the difference.
With 16K lines, it was taking 100 seconds.

To make things worse (with each row it read) the bigger the index grew and the more it had to index through on each iteration, so it took longer than it should have.
The first 1,000 rows took 2.5 Seconds, while the last 1,000 rows took 10.7 Seconds.

Looping through this line of code:

```
SharedStringItem ssi = sst.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(ssi_index);
```

Resulted in this Logged Output:

```
...Using ElementAt():
RowIndex:  1000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 2.4627589
RowIndex:  2000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 2.9460492
RowIndex:  3000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 3.1014865
RowIndex:  4000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 3.76619
RowIndex:  5000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 4.2489844
RowIndex:  6000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 4.7678506
RowIndex:  7000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 5.3871863
RowIndex:  8000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 5.7997721
RowIndex:  9000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 6.4447562
RowIndex: 10000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 6.8978011
RowIndex: 11000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 7.4564455
RowIndex: 12000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 8.2510054
RowIndex: 13000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 8.5758217
RowIndex: 14000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 9.2953823
RowIndex: 15000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 10.0159931
RowIndex: 16000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 10.6884988
Total Seconds: 100.6736451
```

Once I created an intermediary Array to store the SharedStringItem's in for referencing, my time went 100 Seconds down to 10 Seconds and now handles each row in the same amount of time.

This line of code:

```
SharedStringItem[] ssia = sst == null ? null : sst.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ToArray();
Console.WriteLine("ToArray():" + watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " Len:" + ssia.LongCount());
```

and Looping through this line of code:

```
SharedStringItem ssi = ssia[ssi_index];
```

Resulted in this Logged Output:

```
...Using Array[]:
ToArray(): 0.0840583 Len: 33560
RowIndex:  1000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.8057094
RowIndex:  2000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.8183683
RowIndex:  3000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.6809131
RowIndex:  4000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.6530671
RowIndex:  5000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.6086124
RowIndex:  6000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.6232579
RowIndex:  7000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.6369397
RowIndex:  8000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.629919
RowIndex:  9000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.633328
RowIndex: 10000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.6356769
RowIndex: 11000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.663076
RowIndex: 12000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.6633178
RowIndex: 13000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.6580743
RowIndex: 14000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.6518182
RowIndex: 15000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.6662199
RowIndex: 16000 Read: 1,000 Seconds: 0.6360254
Total Seconds: 10.7586264
```

As you can see, converting to an Array took a fraction of a second for 33,560 items and was well worth it to speed up my import process.

Comment: It would be interesting to know that is the class of sst. It looks like its implementation of ElementAt() runs in linear time.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron Good point, I should have included this information.  The sst Variable's Class is [SharedStringTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sharedstringtable).  I ran into this performance issue while using OpenXML to programmatically Read and Write Excel Spreadsheet data.

Answer (score 10):

**Update**: I felt this was an interesting topic and decided to [blog about it](http://philosopherdeveloper.com/posts/such-a-thing-as-too-much-abstraction.html).

Basically, my opinion is that it rarely makes sense to utilize an abstraction for random access *without* requiring `IList<T>`. If you are writing code that wants to access the elements of a collection randomly by index, then just require one that gives you that. And if you're requiring an `IList<T>` to begin with, I really see no point in using `ElementAt` instead of the indexer.

But that's just my opinion, of course.

---

Don't use it for `IList<T>` implementations like `T[]` or `List<T>`. Only use it if you *need* to for collection types which don't provide random access, such as `Queue<T>` or `Stack<T>`.

```
var q = new Queue<int>();
var s = new Stack<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    q.Enqueue(i);
    s.Push(i);
}

// q[1] would not compile.
int fromQueue = q.ElementAt(1);
int fromStack = s.ElementAt(1);
```

Comment: It will use `[]` if the underlying type implements `IList`. LINQ in general always tries to find efficient shortcuts from the underlying types when it can.

Comment: @Matt: That may be, but I still wouldn't use it for such types. It's just pointless: the indexer is there; why not use it directly? Also, the optimizations within the LINQ extension methods are often debatable and in most cases not documented, which means the BCL team could change their minds down the road and take them out.

Comment: They are documented. From MSDN: "If the type of source implements IList<T>, that implementation is used to obtain the element at the specified index".  I have generally found that LINQ has enabled C# code to be of a higher level where I almost never care (or even know) about the underlying types and am just performing operations on enumerations. But that's just been my experience.

Comment: @Matt: That's fair enough. I only meant for that comment to be about optimizations within LINQ extension methods in *general* (which you commented on), though I'll admit I hadn't realized it is specifically documented for `ElementAt`. I still don't believe that it's actually worthwhile to use `ElementAt` in cases where you need random access, though. If you treat this as a useful abstraction that doesn't depend on `IList<T>` you can end up writing some really *bad* code, such as a general `BinarySearch` implementation using `ElementAt` (which I'm hoping you'll agree would be 100% stupid).

Comment: @MattGreer and Dan Tao, it's tempting to just use `ElementAt()` all the time because it allows your code to be more consistent and your code would continue to work regardless of the type of collection. However, if the element grabbing occurs within a loop, you're looking at O(n) for an `IList<T>` vs. O(n^2) otherwise. So, let's say that before you enter the loop, you explicitly convert to an `List<T>`. In *this* case, I would argue for using `[]` rather than `ElementAt()` because it communicates that the lookups are guaranteed to be fast.

Comment: Greetings Dan, your link to your blog seems to be broken, could you provide the updated link if any?

Comment: @DanTao The link is broken.

Comment: Because `IList<T>` does not implement `IList`, it does implement `IEnumerable` however, so I came here looking to check if it is safe to use ElemetAt() or if I should write my own code to check that a property with the declared type of `IList<T>` does actually implement `IList`.

Answer (score 7):

The only reason to use `ElementAt()` over `[]`, is if you have or need an `IEnumerable` instead of an `IList`.

Answer (score 7):

From a semantic standpoint, they both do exactly the same. Whichever you use its not going to change the meaning of the program.

You use `[]`:

1. if the enumerable is *declared* as an `IList<T>`, because:

   **a.** it's more readable, idiomatic, and widely understood. No.1 reason for me to use it.

   **b.** you want to optimize every inch. `[]` should be *marginally* more performant since it's a direct look up and avoids a cast (*note that `ElementAt` uses the indexer if the `IEnumerable<T>` is an `IList<T>`, hence its not a big gain*).

   **c.** you're still in pre .NET 3.5 era.

You use `ElementAt`:

1. if the *declared type* is merely an `IEnumerable<T>`.
2. if `ElementAt` makes it more readable. For eg, in fluent style calls:

   ```
   var x = GetThatList().ElementAt(1).Wash().Spin().Rinse().Dry();

   //is more readable than

   var x = GetThatList()[1].Wash().Spin().Rinse().Dry();
   ```
3. if you are really adamant on using a consistent style for both `IList<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

In simple terms, if you have the variable declared as `IList<T>` use `[]`, otherwise use `ElementAt` (*I stress the point "declared" because even if your `IEnumerable<T>` is an `IList<T>` underneath, you can only use `ElementAt`. Casting to `IList<T>` to use the indexer is a no no (it happens inside `ElementAt` anyway)*). Readability triumphs. If you have that in mind its simple to choose. Indexer style is what I have to use in vast majority of cases. I'm forced to use `ElementAt` very rarely.

Answer (score 6):

`ElementAt()` does attempt to cast as `IList<T>` first then use the indexer, so performance with `ElementAt()` probably won't be significantly different than using the indexer directly. So even if you have an `IList<T>`, you may want to consider `ElementAt()`, if there's ever a possibility that you'd change your declared type in the future.

Comment: The point about possibly switching declared type is a good one!  I think the reason I've been using .ElementAt() is due to habit from all the Queues that I use.

Answer (score 5):

`IEnumerable` doesn't support direct index access, if you *know* you have a list, keep using the second form, since it is much easier to read (arguably).

`ElementAt()` is supported for all enumerations, not just lists - performance wise they are the same when used on a type of `IList` (i.e. a generic List), but if you have a list using the index access is more expressive. If you look at the source of `ElementAt()` with reflector, you will see that it will internally use the index access if the `IEnumerable` is of type `IList`:

```
..
IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
if (list != null)
{
    return list[index];
}
..
```

Comment: @xanatos - certainly if you want to build your own `IList` type that way ;-) `List<T>` at least uses an array as backing store, so for those it will be O(1)

Comment: Great for including the source code