# Reach/access a specific index in IEnumerable object in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to access a specific item from IEnumerable @model ;

I know that I can reach all item by below code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodName)
        </td>
}
```

But I need to access the third item (as an example) by doing somthing like that :
    Model[3].FoodName

Are there are any way to reach a specific index item from IEnumerable object in MVC ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326874/why-would-i-use-enumerable-elementat-versus-the-operator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [`ElementAt(index)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) extension method:

```
Model.ElementAt(2)
```

Or change the model type from `IEnumerable<T>` to `IList<T>` or `T[]`:

```
@model IList<SomeViewModel>
```

now you could loop with an index:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].FoodName)    
}
```

This is the preferred approach if you generate input fields (EditorFor, TextBoxFor, ...) because this way correct names will be assigned to them.