# What's the point of Enumerable.ElementAt<TSource>?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

`IEnumerable<T>` exposes an enumerator, so the object can be enumerated. There is nothing about indexes exposed by this interface. `IList<T>` is about indexes, as it exposes the `IndexOf` method.

So what's the point of Enumerable.ElementAt? I just read the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of this LINQ extension method:

> Returns the element at a specified index in a sequence.

Well, yes, it's about a **sequence**, not just an `IEnumerable`. Reading the remarks:

> If the type of source implements IList, that implementation is used
>   to obtain the element at the specified index. Otherwise, this method
>   obtains the specified element.

Okay, so if the concrete type implements something that inherits from `IList<T>` (which is an actual sequence), then it's the same as `IndexOf()`. If not, it iterates until the index is reached.

Here's a sample scenario:

```
// Some extension method exposed by a lib
// I know it's not a good piece of code, but let's say it's coded this way:
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    // Returns true if all elements are ordered
    public static bool IsEnumerableOrdered(this IEnumerable<int> value)
    {
        // Iterates over elements using an index
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            if (value.ElementAt(i) > value.ElementAt(i + 1))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

// Here's a collection that is enumerable, but doesn't always returns
// its objects in the same order
public class RandomAccessEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private List<T> innerList;
    private static Random rnd = new Random();

    public RandomAccessEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        innerList = list.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var listCount = this.innerList.Count;
        List<int> enumeratedIndexes = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listCount; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = -1;
            while (randomIndex < 0 || enumeratedIndexes.Contains(randomIndex))
            {
                randomIndex = rnd.Next(listCount);
            }

            enumeratedIndexes.Add(randomIndex);
            yield return this.innerList[randomIndex];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

// Here's some test program
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var test0 = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
        var test1 = new RandomAccessEnumerable<int>(test0);

        Console.WriteLine("With List");
        Console.WriteLine(test0.IsEnumerableOrdered()); // true
        Console.WriteLine(test0.IsEnumerableOrdered()); // true
        Console.WriteLine(test0.IsEnumerableOrdered()); // true
        Console.WriteLine(test0.IsEnumerableOrdered()); // true
        Console.WriteLine(test0.IsEnumerableOrdered()); // true

        Console.WriteLine("With RandomAccessEnumerable");
        Console.WriteLine(test1.IsEnumerableOrdered()); // might be true or false
        Console.WriteLine(test1.IsEnumerableOrdered()); // might be true or false
        Console.WriteLine(test1.IsEnumerableOrdered()); // might be true or false
        Console.WriteLine(test1.IsEnumerableOrdered()); // might be true or false
        Console.WriteLine(test1.IsEnumerableOrdered()); // might be true or false

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

So, as `RandomAccessEnumerable` might return enumerated objects in a random order, you just can't rely on the simple `IEnumerable<T>` interface to assume your elements are indexed. So you don't want to use `ElementAt` for an `IEnumerable`.

In the above example, I think `IsEnumerableOrdered` should require a `IList<T>` parameter as it implies elements are a sequence. I actually can't find a scenario where the `ElementAt` method is useful, and not bug-prone.

Comment: It would probably make more sense for [`IOrderedEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534852.aspx) types.

Comment: *it's about a sequence, not just an IEnumerable*: and how exactly do you define a "sequence"? For me the IEnumerable interface represents a sequence of elements, no more, no less... Most of the time the elements in an IEnumerable will be returned in the same order; your RandomAccessEnumerable example is too contrived to be really relevant.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque For me, a sequence is an ordered list of objects

Comment: So, what's the problem? That's why this method have **remarks** on msdn.

Comment: Well, `LinkedList` is a sequence but it doesn't implement `IList` :(

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The problem is that it's really bug-prone and actually useless IMHO.

Comment: Just because you've come up with a poorly-coded use of `ElementAt`, and an `IEnumerable` that gives non-deterministic results for _many_ `Enumerable` methods, doesn't mean `ElementAt` is useless or bug-prone.

Comment: @ken2k, yes, but except in contrived cases like your RandomAccessEnumerable class, the items will remain in the same order. You could just as easily make an IList implementation that returns a random item for any index. It's your responsibility to use ElementAt only when it makes sense..

Comment: @ken2k instead of using `Skip(9).First()` you can use `ElementAt(10)`. Why not?

Comment: I agree for the really poor-written RandomAccessEnumerable class. But when you write a lib an expose methods that take IEnumerable as parameter, you don't know how it'll be used by other people. So you only use IEnumerable for what it actually is, i.e. something that can be enumerated and has no index.

Comment: @ken2k it would be a bug, if there will be no remarks on expected results of this method. But msdn clearly points how this method works with `IList`. Nothing unexpected for me.

Comment: @ken2k - when you write a lib, and just get handed an `IEnumerable`, there are *all kinds* of things that you don't know. Is it safe to enumerate it more than once? That's why you document *your* expectations for your library methods and expect people using your library to meet them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Fair point, +1 for your example of multiple enumerations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many `IEnumerable` types like  array or list. All `IList` types(which [`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czz5hkty.aspx) also implements) have an [**indexer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) which you can use to access elements at a specific index.

This will be used by `Enumerable.ElementAt` if the sequence can be casted to `IList` successfully. Otherwise it will be enumerated.

So it's just a convenient way to access elements at a given index for all kind of `IEnumerable` types.

This has the advantage that you can change the type later without needing to change all occurences of `arr[index]`.

For what it's worth, here's the reflected(ILSpy) method to demonstrate what i've said:

```
public static TSource ElementAt<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int index)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        return list[index];
    }
    if (index < 0)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
    }
    TSource current;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (index == 0)
            {
                current = enumerator.Current;
                return current;
            }
            index--;
        }
        throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: Well I do understand the way `ElementAt` works, I was just wondering why someone would use it for non-IList objects, as we can't assume an `IEnumerable` object always returns its items in the same order.

Comment: 1. because he might use a query today and a `IList` tomorrow. For example: `items.Where(i=>i%2==0).Take(10).OrderBy(i=>i).ElementAt(5)`  You don't need to modify the implementation if you want another collection, just prepend `ToList` or `ToArray`  and it still works.

Comment: I see your (valid) point. What I still don't get is why someone would use `items.Where(i=>i%2==0).Take(10).OrderBy(i=>i).ElementAt(5)` in the first place with items as an `IEnumerable`, knowing that `IEnumerable` is not ordered per definition (so there is no index).

Comment: I guess I'm just over-thinking about that, maybe it's just like Skip() or Take() as others said.

Comment: @ken2k: The query above is ordered. Not every `IEnumerable` is unordered (f.e. a `Dictionary` is unordered *and* an `IEnumerable`).

Comment: True, I didn't see the OrderBy() :) I think you answered my question by providing a valid example of useful usage of ElemenAt