# Getting a list item by index

Tags: c#, list

I've recently started using c# moving over from Java. I can't seem to find how to get a list item by index. In java to get the first item of the list it would be:

```
list1.get(0);
```

What is the equivalent in c#?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326874/why-would-i-use-enumerable-elementat-versus-the-operator for some discussion as to whether to use the [] operator or the ElementAt() method.

Comment: @user1909486: you haven't accepted any answers to your questions

Answer (score 512):

```
list1[0];
```

Assuming list's type has an indexer defined.

Comment: The only answer that explains why it's possible to access a list, which is an object, like an array

Comment: Does it return a copy of the object in the list?
obj = list[0];
list.clear();
// will obj still be populated?

Comment: @Paul McCarthy: you could easily test this yourself, but Yes. A list hold references to objects. Clearing the list does not affect the objects held in it. If there are no other references to those objects, they will be garbage collected at some point in time.

Answer (score 316):

You can use the ElementAt extension method on the list.

For example:

```
// Get the first item from the list

using System.Linq;

var myList = new List<string>{ "Yes", "No", "Maybe"};
var firstItem = myList.ElementAt(0);

// Do something with firstItem
```

Comment: Just to note that ElementAt() requires `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: Is there any advantage to this over the standard `myList[0]` notation?

Comment: "Why would I use Enumerable.ElementAt() versus the [] operator?"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326874/why-would-i-use-enumerable-elementat-versus-the-operator

Comment: `.ElementAtOrDefault();`

Comment: @AnalogWeapon yes there is - you can use it as part of a null safe chain, e.g. `myCollectionWhichMightBeNull?.ElementAt(0)` or to safeguard againt a non-existent element: `myCollection.ElementAtOrDefault(0)?.SomeProperty`

Comment: Can you pass a integer constant to either [] or ElementAt? Rather than literal numbers?

Comment: @Lavande: another advantage is you can use ElementAt() for .Net collection types that don't support [].

Answer (score 44):

Visual Basic, C#, and C++ all have syntax for accessing the Item property without using its name. Instead, the variable containing the List is used as if it were an array:

```
List[index]
```

See, for instance, [List.Item[Int32] Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item).

Answer (score 26):

.NET [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) data structure is an [`Array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.array) in a "mutable shell".

So you can use indexes for accessing to it's elements like:

```cs
var firstElement = myList[0];
var secondElement = myList[1];
```

Starting with **C# 8.0** you can use [`Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.index) and [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range) classes for accessing elements. They provides accessing from the end of sequence or just access a specific part of sequence:

```cs
var lastElement = myList[^1]; // Using Index
var fiveElements = myList[2..7]; // Using Range, note that 7 is exclusive
```

You can combine indexes and ranges together:

```cs
var elementsFromThirdToEnd = myList[2..^0]; // Index and Range together
```

Also you can use LINQ `ElementAt` method but for 99% of cases this is really not necessary and just slow performance solution.

Answer (score 21):

Old question, but I see that this thread was fairly recently active, so I'll go ahead and throw in my two cents:

Pretty much exactly what Mitch said. Assuming proper indexing, you can just go ahead and use square bracket notation as if you were accessing an array. In addition to using the numeric index, though, if your members have specific names, you can often do kind of a simultaneous search/access by typing something like:

```
var temp = list1["DesiredMember"];
```

The more you know, right?

Answer (score 18):

you can use index to access list elements

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1[0] //for getting the first element of the list
```