# how to find an element in a list by its index

Tags: c#, list

For example I want to find the third element of this list by its index

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> list;
Random random = new Random();
list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

int i;  
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(random.Next(0, 5), random.Next(0, 5)));
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]=[{1}]", list.Count, list.);
}
```

thanks for the help

Comment: just `list[index_you_need]`

Comment: how can i use the list.find()

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `.ElementAt(i)`, although using the normal `list[i]` index accessor should also work.

Answer (score 0):

I think `list[index]` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `list1[0];`

For more information use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20048587/4513879)