# How to access object's property in inside other object's property?

Tags: c#, object, mvvm, devexpress, bindinglist

```
//class MessageModel
public class MessageModel
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public BindingList<AttachDocument> _attachDocument {get;set;};
}
// class AttachDocument that it's object is a MessageModel property
public class AttachDocument
{
    public string AttachName { get; set; }
    public bool IsCheck { get; set; }
}

MessageModel source = new MessageModel { AttachDocument = new BindingList<AttachDocument>()};
MessageModel value = new MessageModel { AttachDocument = new BindingList<AttachDocument>()};
// Error "AttachName" is not defined
source.AttachDocument.AttachName = value.AttachDocument.AttachName; // What I want to access
```

So how can I access access object's property in inside other object's property and assign a value.

Comment: Please edit your question as it makes no sense, give and example please and be more specific

Comment: What do you mean by _property in inside property_ ? Show your expected output

Comment: Your `BindingList<AttachDocument>` is not a property. Add `get; set;` so that it becomes a property. also change `private` to `public`.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property with the name `AttachDocument`. It is a class that is unrelated to the field you are having defined. There are a few issues you need to address:

- First, you need to make the field `public`, to make it accessible outside of your class;
- Second, you need to make it a property to follow conventions, and help binding it in WPF for example;
- Third, the list should be addressed by index, but only after you have added an item to it.

Since you want to iterate over the list, you need something like a `foreach`:

```
public class MessageModel
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public BindingList<AttachDocument> AttachDocuments {get;set;}
}

foreach (AttachDocument s in source.AttachDocuments)
{
    AttachDocument t = new AttachDocument();
    t.AttachName = s.AttachName;

    value.AttachDocuments.Add(t);
}
```

Comment: It's working if we use loop but how to access without loop?

Comment: `source.AttachDocuments[0]`, for the first one, if there has been any added.

Comment: @BenniTo Do you need more help?

Comment: Thanks, It's working to use loop and I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *property* for AttachDocument in your class, only a member variable. That needs to be wrapped in a get/set first.

Then the AttachDocument property is a list of AttachDocument instances, not a single one so the problem you have is that AttachName isn’t a property *on the list*.

[This is how you can use indexers to get an element by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456845/getting-a-list-item-by-index)

Comment: There is no *The AttachDocument property*. There is a class by that name though.

Comment: *That needs to be wrapped in a get/set first.* No, it doesn't need to be a property to be accessible. Making it `public` would help though.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that but it had been mentioned in the comments above... I’ve modified the answer to include that issue too!

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @PatrickHofman I think you’ll find he asked how to access the objects “Property”. So...

Comment: Usually, links are not answers.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want this:

```
MessageModel source = new MessageModel { AttachDocument = new BindingList<AttachDocument>()};
source._attachDocument[myIndex].AttachName = "Name";
```

However this assumes you already created an instance of `AttachDocument` and assigned added it into the `_attachDocument`-list of your `source`:

```
MessageModel source = new MessageModel { _attachDocument = new BindingList<AttachDocument>()};
source._attachDocument.Add(myDocument);
```

As an aside `_attachDocument` is a bad name for a public property. You should definitly follow the naming-conventions. So change `_attachDocument` to `AttachDocument`. A property can have the same name as the class of its type. However in your case the property is a list of documents, so the best name would be `AttachDocuments` with "s" at the end. This makes it clear that the property is some kind of collection which needs an index to be accessed.