# What do these two lines mean in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, penetration-testing

What does ":" and "+2" mean in `[:http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+2]`?
What does "("/")" and "[1]" mean in `.split("/")[1]`?

```
def get_http_headers(http_payload):
    try:
        # split the headers off if it is HTTP traffic
        headers_raw = http_payload[:http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+2]

        # break out the headers
        headers = dict(re.findall(r"(?P<name>.*?): (? P<value>.*?)\r\n", headers_raw))

    except:
        return None

    return headers

def extract_image(headers, http_payload):
    image = None
    image_type = None

    try:
        if "image" in headers["Content-Type"]:
            # grab the image type and image body
            image_type = headers["Content-Type"].split("/")[1]

            image = http_payload[http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+4:]



            except:
                pass
    except:
        return None, None

    return image, image_type
```

Comment: There are 3 distinct questions here (or 5, depending on how you count). This is not really the format expected here, which is a specific problem you have, with some proof you have attempted to solve it.

Comment: @SamuelDion-Girardeau question updated. An answer would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456845/getting-a-list-item-by-index.

Comment: Look for slicing in this page.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

or https://www.datadependence.com/2016/05/python-sequence-slicing-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http_payload[:http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+2]` [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) the string `http_payload` so that only the head of the string up to the first appearance of "\r\n\r\n" and the first "\r\n" remains. the `.index()` method of a string will return the index of the first appearance of the pattern in the string.

Example:

```
test = "abcdefg"
# slicing:
print(test[1:3])  # will output 'bc'

# index:
print(test.index('bc'))  # will output 1 (index of start of substring 'bc')

# either start or end (or both) of the slice can be left out, so the following is equivalent:
print(test[:2] == test[0:2])  # will output True
```

---

`.split("/")[1]` will split a string at "/" characters and return a list, from which the item with index 1 is accessed.
See the following code for example:

```
test = "/this/is/a/path"
print(test.split("/"))  # will output ["this", "is", "a", "path"]
print(test.split("/")[0])  # will output "is" since element of index 1 of the resulting list is accessed.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please give a simple example for each?
And what is the meaning of ":" and "+2" in "[:http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")+2]"? Thanks a lot for you help!

Comment: Help would be highly appreciated! @dudenr33

Comment: Please read the link provided. The ":" separates the start and end index of the slice.
`http_payload.index("\r\n\r\n")` will return an integer, to which the "+2" gets added.
So if this evaluates to 10 (for example), it would be equivalent to `http_payload[:12]`, which is short for `http_payload[0:12]`.
This basically means "take the characters 0 to 12 from string `http_payload`".

Please work through a Python tutorial of your choice and refer to the Python docs before asking questions on StackOverflow. StackOverflow is neither a replacement for the former nor for the latter.