# the nested list doesn't appear in intellisense visual studio

Tags: c#, class, model

I have this model as you can see :

```
public class UserNotes : BaseEntity
    {
        public IList<SymbolNotes> SymbolsNotes { get; set; }

        public UserNotes(string userId): base($"UserNotes/{userId}")
        {
        }

    }
    public class SymbolNotes
    {
        public string Isin { get; set; }
        public List<NoteItem> Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

Now in my code I declare a variable named `userNotes`,
[image]

But when I put the point the `SymbolsNotes` doesn't in the list why ?
[image]

Comment: Because your `userNotes` is `IEnumerable`, write `userNotes.Select(x => x.SymbolNotes)`

Comment: SymbolNotes is part of class UserNotes not of the List of UserNotess. You would need to select one UserNotes object from list first. What do you want to accomplish?
Do you really need list of UserNotes? Do you want to get single SymbolNotes list or all SymbolNotes lists from all UserNotes objects?

Comment: I want to add a symbolnote  like this :  userNotes.SymbolsNotes.Add(newSymbolNotes);

Comment: @Ortund  I want to do this : userNotes.SymbolsNotes.Add(newSymbolNotes);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable `userNotes` that contains a `IList` of the class `UserNotes`. To simplify, you can imagine that you have a collection of box on which you wrote an integer (the index of the box in the collection), and the content of each box you have is an instance of the `UserNotes` class.

When you write `userNotes.` , you target the collection of box. So to access the content of the class `UserNotes`, you will have to target a specific box to look the content inside to access the instance. Then only you will be able to access the property `SymbolsNotes`.

Another way of visualizing it is like a paper dictionary, it has a lot of translations but you cannot just say to the editor "change the description", you will have to say "change the description of the first word in the dictionary", or "change the description of the word 'banana' ".

In C#, you have multiple possibilities to do it :

- [Selecting by the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456845/getting-a-list-item-by-index/15456851)
- [Selecting the first item with the `FirstOrDefault` Linq method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0)
- [Selecting one item that respects a condition with the `Single` Linq method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?view=net-6.0)

Of course many other way exists but I juste wrote 3 of the most commons ways to do it.

And you could it like this :

### Use the index

```cs
userNotes[0].SymbolsNotes.Add(newSymbolNotes);
```

### Use the `First` Linq method

```cs
userNotes.First().SymbolsNotes.Add(newSymbolNotes);
```

### use the `Single` Linq method

```cs
userNotes.Single(/* Condition with lambda expression */).SymbolsNotes.Add(newSymbolNotes);
```