# Show Mulitple Files that Meet Criteria, But Select One of Them

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to collect a series of filenames that meet certain criteria, and then pass that collection for the user to select the correct one.  No problem doing that, except when I am trying to actually access the particular file selected.

```
string URL = "whateverPath";
string filename = "whateverFileName";
string pattern = @"\\" + filename + @"N?\..{3}";
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(URL).
    Where(path => Regex.Match(path, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success);
```

This gives me a collection of files, but I am not allowed to choose files[2], for example, because of the way IEnumerable is constructed (whoever heard of an enumerable that can't be accessed by an index?--kind of makes it...not enumerable!)

So, when I try to use the Directory.GetFiles method, which returns a string array, I am suddenly not allowed to use the Linq pattern matching shortcut, because that only returns an IEnumerable.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(URL).
Where(path => Regex.Match(path, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success);
```

This does not compile.

Is there any easy way to get an index number from the IEnumerable, or to use Linq to match my pattern?

Comment: If you put a `ToArray()` on the end of it, you can index it that way.

Comment: @paqogomez - this should be the answer, not a comment.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for pointing out a very simple solution!

Comment: Have you tried [`ElementAt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb299233(v=vs.100).aspx)?  [Why would I use Enumerable.ElementAt() versus the index operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326874/why-would-i-use-enumerable-elementat-versus-the-operator)

Comment: @ErikPhilips: I would not recommend `ElementAt()` unless you know you're only ever going to want a single element. The overhead of creating a list is usually miniscule compared to the risk of re-evaluating the enumerable multiple times.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior If you have any comments on the pros/cons of ElementAt vs indexer, I suggest you put an answer on the link I provided.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: That question is asking about which one to use when you've already got a List, whereas my comment applies specifically to situations where the collection isn't (yet) backed by a structure that supports random access, as in this question. Also, the top two voted answers on that link recommend against using `ElementAt()`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior you make me laugh.  Actually the question was not specific about `List`, as one the answers states: `If the underlying type supports random access (ie, it supports the [] operator), then ElementAt will make use of that. So the only overhead is an extra method call (which is almost never relevant).`  Also I'm not advocating anything, I just ask him if he tried it.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Glad I could brighten your day. ;-) "Have you tried [X]?" came across as a recommendation when I read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Linq` includes an extension method of `IEnumerable`, `ToList()`. So just add a `.ToList()`:

```
IList<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(URL)
    .Where(path => Regex.Match(path, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I am choosing this answer, even though there appear to be many possible solutions.  .ElementAt does not seem to work with a nullable int, and arrays always seem less flexible than lists (to me, anyway), so I will use a list.  Thanks for all the quick responses.

Comment: @RicGaudet why you need to use nullable int for index what behavior do you expect when you try to get the element at `null` index? It doesn't make any sense. PS. Neither `ElementAt` nor the lists accept nullable int for index.

Comment: I guess that's true.  I used nullable int only because I used a form to get a response from the user, and if the form is closed before a selection is chosen, the that's what you get (please correct me if that is not true!)

Answer (score 1):

Every LINQ extension method works on IEnumerable and returns IEnumerable. This interface hasn't indexer. You can get element at certain index by using the extension method `ElementAt(index)`. This will enumerate the collection till reach the specified index and will returns the element.

Other approach can be to convert your collection to list or array via extension methods `ToList()` and `ToArray()` and then use their indexers but this will proceed the whole collection and convert it to list/array which can be a little slower.