# How to extract part of a textbox to another textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, parsing, visual-studio-2015, textbox

I want to extract part of a textbox to another textbox. So I have 2 textboxes namely txtuser and txtpassword. When scanning QR, selecting txtuser automatically separates the results of the scanner to txt.user and txtpassword .

Thanks

```
'This is the result of the QR barcode scanner
USERNAME : TEST-PASSWORD : TEST@123


'so the result I want

txtuser.txt     = TEST
txtPassword.txt = TEST@123
```

```
'code in keypress
 Private Sub txtUser_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtUser.KeyPress
 Const pattern As String = "USERNAME : (\S+)-PASSWORD : (\S+)"
  If e.KeyChar = ChrW(8) Then
        Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(txtUser.Text, pattern)
        If m.Success Then
  e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Back
            txtUser.Text = m.Groups(1).Value
            txtPassword.Text = m.Groups(2).Value
        Else
            'TODO: display some message
        End If
     End If
    End Sub
```

Update screenshot of answer from @OlivierJacotDescombes

[screenshot breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx4K5.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAxtS.png)

If I use the code update just now then in "txtuser" the full results of the scan appear then I press back space then it automatically becomes each according to the textbox

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @OlivierJacot-Descombes great answer, you can also split the string

```vb
Dim input = "USERNAME : TEST-PASSWORD : TEST@123"
Dim split = input.Split({"-", ":"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Function(s) s.Trim())
txtUser.Text = split(1)
txtPassword.Text = split(3)
```

This requires that the chars `-` and `:` not be used in usernames and passwords however. You can see that it creates an enumerable of the items which are not those chars, so you just index that for the appropriate strings.

```vb
For Each s In split
    Debug.Print(s)
Next
```

> USERNAME
>
> TEST
>
> PASSWORD
>
> TEST@123

If the barcode scanner puts a carriage return at the end of the scan, you can process once that key is seen. It should not lead to additional processing as long as enter is not pressed

```vb
Private Sub txtUser_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtUser.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then
        parseBarcodeScan(txtUser.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub parseBarcodeScan(input As String)
    Dim split = input.Split({"-", ":"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Function(s) s.Trim())
    txtUser.Text = split(1)
    txtPassword.Text = split(3)
End Sub
```

The regex answer is superior in terms of handling passwords with the tokens I use to split. I would recommend using that inside the Sub I posted above.

Comment: This works only if there is no "-" or ":" in the name or password. it is missing a `.ToArray()`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the `IEnumerable` from `Split.Select` can be indexed, no need for `.ToArray()` here. Anyway, OP should get your solution working ;)

Comment: obviously this is possible due to VB's [Default Query Indexer](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/blob/main/spec/expressions.md#default-query-indexer). I didn't know about that. But note that this will enumerate the `IEnumerable(Of T)` every time, so don't do this repeatedly for large indexes.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes not exactly, though `ElementAtOrDefault` is related to `ElementAt` which is related to `[]`. You can see both `ElementAt` and `[]` are available to IEnumerable in C# as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5326874/832052 as long as the underlying type supports random access using `[]`. Not sure if this has anything to do with it coming from an array before Select, I suspect it doesn't. But Select's output IEnumerable sure supports `[]`.

Comment: You are calling `Select` which returns an `IEnumerable` based on an [Iterator](https://www.dotnetperls.com/iterator-vbnet) which does not return an array or List or any other indexable collection. `ElementAt` can only take the shortcut of true indexing if the underlying type is indexable. Therefore, it will have to iterate and count until it finds the element to be returned.

Comment: @djv , thanks for your answer but  `Dim input As String = txtuser.Text` If I change the input variable to textbox user then there is no result from the scan

Comment: @user18 I never recommended you do that. You will need to figure out how to pass your string into the function. It's clear you have other UI event issues from all three posts on this page.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes splitting hairs, Iterating 6 elements vs. allocating an Array

Comment: @djv , can the function be directly in txtuser if it can how can I do

Comment: @user18 I updated my answer with a function

Comment: @user18 does that make [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76314933/832052) obsolete? You should use the other answer's method as it's the superior method. But put it in my Sub

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```vb
Dim input As String = "USERNAME : TEST-PASSWORD : TEST@123"
Dim pattern As String = "USERNAME : (\S+)-PASSWORD : (\S+)"
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern)

If m.Success Then
    Dim user As String = m.Groups(1).Value
    Dim password As String = m.Groups(2).Value
    Console.WriteLine($"User = {user}, Password = {password}")
Else
    Console.WriteLine("no match")
End If
```

Console output:

```
User = TEST, Password = TEST@123
```

Explanation of the regex pattern `USERNAME : (\S+)-PASSWORD : (\S+)`:

- `(\S+)` capturing groups 1 and 2 matching at least one non-white-space-character for the user name and the password.
- everything else matches "as is".

With the textboxes:

```vb
Const pattern As String = "USERNAME : (\S+)-PASSWORD : (\S+)"
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(txtUser.Text, pattern)

If m.Success Then
    txtUser.Text = m.Groups(1).Value
    txtPassword.Text = m.Groups(2).Value
Else
   'TODO: display some message
End If
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but your answer uses C# program language even though my post uses the tag vb.net

Comment: Sorry. Changed it to VB. The procedure is exactly the same, just with another syntax.

Comment: thanks your answer, I use keypress from txtuser how I implement your code with my code `Dim user As String = m.Groups(1).Value Dim password As String = m.Groups(2).Value` I created it like with my code `Dim user As String = m.txtuser.text Dim password As String = m.txtpassword.text` because there is an error if I make code like that

Comment: it is `txtUser.Text` and `txtPassword.Text` not `.Value` as I wrote earlier. Discard the `m.` in front of the textbox names.

Comment: Update the answer code from you with the textbox `txtUser.Value  txtPassword.Value` So it must be changed to `txtUser.text  txtPassword.text` and 
I have an error  `txtuser.KeyPress and  Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types`

Comment: Don't declare the events manually. Select the events from the properties window. This will add them correctly. See [How to handle a control event (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-add-an-event-handler). You can select VB at the top of the page to get the examples in VB. If you declared the textboxes manually, add the `WithEvents` keyword: `Dim WithEvents txtUser As New TextBox`.

Comment: Thank you,the error problem has been solved but the result of your code `EST@123TEST in txtuser and T in txtpassword`

Comment: It works for me. See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9NY87P. Has the text scrolled to the left in the TextBox maybe? If this is the case, then you may fix it with `txtUser.SelectionStart = 0 : txtUser.SelectionLength = 1`

Comment: `txtUser.SelectionStart = 0 : txtUser.SelectionLength = 1` if I use it then it appears `3 in txtuser `
if I check from the right it appears in the user textbox

Comment: if it is run in the console then no problem appears but if it is run in a textbox then a problem like that appears

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are doing with `KeyPress`, But maybe you are swallowing some characters there? [Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/tutorial-debugger) your code to see what you get from `txtUser` before doing the split.

Comment: sorry I replied late, I updated the screenshot as you requested and updated the keypress code from the txtuser

Comment: KeyPress will be fired after every character entered. This is not good. You should wait until the QR scanner has finished entering the text. Maybe it terminates its entry with a special character like Chr(13), Chr(10) or Chr(9). Only execute this logic when this character is entered.

Comment: If I use the code update just now then in "txtuser" the full results of the scan appear then I press back space then it automatically becomes each according to the textbox. Can the backspace be automatic without having me press the backspace key on the keyboard or is there another code solution