# Can automatic press backspace when scanning barcodes in the textbox on the vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, keypress, barcode-scanner, backspace

Can automatic press backspace when scanning barcodes in the textbox on the vb.net?

is there any other solution or my code is wrong?

Thanks

```
 Private Sub txtUser_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtUser.KeyPress
 Const pattern As String = "USERNAME : (\S+)-PASSWORD : (\S+)"
  If e.KeyChar = ChrW(8) Then
        Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(txtUser.Text, pattern)
        If m.Success Then
  e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Back
            txtUser.Text = m.Groups(1).Value
            txtPassword.Text = m.Groups(2).Value
        Else
            'TODO: display some message
        End If
     End If
    End Sub
```

Result scanner in txtuser
[image: VIEW1]

Result scanner after press backspace in keyboard.
so I want immediate results without pressing backspace on the keyboard as below
[image: view2]

Comment: You should execute this code automatically when you receive data from the scanner.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville , 
thanks for your reply, how can I do as per your recommendation

Comment: Somewhere in your project there is code that updates `txtUser.Text` with the `USERNAME: TEST-PASSWORD: TEST@123` data you get from the scanner. When that code executes, you can perform the `Regex.Match(txtUser.Text, pattern)` test.

Comment: Depending on the scanner of course, it's pretty common to be able to have the scanner send a carriage return at the end of a scan.  If it's not on by default, there is usually a way to switch it on via a device programming barcode.

Answer (score 0):

The barcode scanners add an enter at the end of the text. You can handle the keydown event instead of keypress to detect when Enter key is pressed and do something like that:

```
Private Sub txtUser_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtUser.KeyDown
    Const pattern As String = "USERNAME : (\S+)-PASSWORD : (\S+)"
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(txtUser.Text, pattern)
        If m.Success Then
            txtUser.Text = m.Groups(1).Value
            txtPassword.Text = m.Groups(2).Value
        Else
            'TODO: display some message
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

With this code, you don't need to press the backspace key to split the barcode input into the two fields.

I hope that is helpful.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I got an error `Error BC30456 'KeyCode' is not a member of 'KeyPressEventArgs'`

Comment: @user18 You need to change your event handler from `KeyPress`to `KeyDown`. The `e.KeyKode` is in KeyEventArg. Look at the code I share with you in the answer.